# jConfirm alerte - plugin jQuery/php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, confirm

I am using jConfirm for confirm dialog with success.

> Here is the code

```
<script>  
function DeleteUser(){  
if (window.jConfirm('Etes-vous sur de modifier?')) {  
document.window.dform.submit(); //on envoie le formulaire  
} else {return false;}  
}  
</script>  

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="dform " id="dform" onsubmit="return DeleteUser();">  
<input type="submit" value="Modifier" name="modifier"/>  
</form>
```

The problem is that the dialog is show but does not wait for user answer and continues.

When change to classic javascript confirm everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is in other similar posts:

[jConfirm with this existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701772/jconfirm-with-this-existing-code)

[jConfirm alert - jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373331/jconfirm-alert-jquery-plugin)

Regards