# how to call jconfirm jquery from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

i call JCONFIRM inside my JS file but doesnt work :

```
jConfirm('Title', 'Are you sure?', function(r) {     
if(r)
{
alert("true");
}
else
{
alert("false");
}
 });
```

did i miss any lib ?

Comment: Read this.. [jConfirm alert jquery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373331/jconfirm-alert-jquery-plugin)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701772/jconfirm-with-this-existing-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474783/how-to-get-jconfirm-return-value

Comment: my problem with this simple syntaxe my Jconfirm doesnt appear :jConfirm('Title', 'Are you sure?', function(r) {     
if(r)
{
alert("true");
}
else
{
alert("false");
}
 });

Comment: Can you produce a sample of your problem in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: my problem is simple just when i call jConfirm inside my JS doesnt appear . did i miss any lib ??

Comment: maybe the jConfirm lib ?

Comment: did Jconfirm have a lib to be added ??

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is correct
You have to **following library** to be work

- jquery-1.8.3.min.js
- jquery.alerts.js
- jquery.alerts.css
  **Download Link**
  jquery.alerts.css - [bvbcode](http://www.bvbcode.com/code/n0kb35yd-183647-down)
  jquery.alerts.js - [bvbcode](http://www.bvbcode.com/code/n0kb35yd-183646-down)

Comment: i added the jquery.jconfirm-1.0.min.js but still doesnt work.

Comment: see the example that i puted

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example that i used but doesnt work

Updated :

idk why Jconfirm doesnt work

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.alerts.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    jConfirm('Title', 'Are you sure?', function(r) {     
if(r)
{
alert("true");
}
else
{
alert("false");
}
 });
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
     alert("test");
  });
});
</script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

thats what i get when i click on "Append text"
[image]

still doesnt work

**Update 2** : i added Jquery 1.6.1 and it works thats what i get :
[image]

why i have this A OK A ???

Update 3: problem fixed i changed in jquery.alerts.js this :

```
okButton: ' OK ',
cancelButton: ' Cancel ',
```

to this :

okButton: 'OK',
    cancelButton: 'Cancel',

Comment: me too i use chrome and firefox ... i will show you a screen of what i see

Comment: yes i use chrome too see my update i showed you what i see when i click in append text that have the Jconfirm code .

Comment: yes no alert just the screenshot that i show you have what i get when i click

Comment: hmm problem in latest js (jquery-1.9.1.min.js)...it working in jquery-1.6.1.min.js

Comment: Bug in alerts.js (If you still want to use 1.9 then you should comment the code below 2 line of code //IE6 Fix into alerts.js - but will not work for IE)

Comment: try to change the content of okButton into alerts.js